# Question about karmyog(need guidance)

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavad-gita, karma, sacrifice

I want to ask few things

1. how to sacrifice all my karma to shri hari? Is it a mental state , if yes please describe?
2. if problems arises I get a bit tense and anxious , ***so is being a little anxious and doubtful allowed in karmyog***? Although, I can continue my work in doubt and anxiety
3. is enjoying sensual pleasure allowed in karmyog (*could arjun enjoy kingdom won after war being surrendered to shri hari/parmatma)*
   In my case let's suppose I have completed my daily work can I go to restaurant/watch TV etc. **Being surrendered to God I should completely renounce sensual pleasure and do my duties or is little pleasure allowed**.If complete withdrawl of senses is  required , what to do during free time(meditate on parmatma Or my free choice)
4. sometimes ***random lustful thoughts pop up in my mind*** and i immediately kill them. So is it possible to remain surrendered to God while being in lust for few span of time

> Karmayog was told to surya dev also.If I want to read other texts
> regarding karma yoga (other than gita)Please give link or tell book and adhyay where it was told in detail

Now if I start karmyog I will fail initially due to( lack of self control+phone addiction +emotions and desires)

**so please tell me something for self control which I should try for a week or two or month then I should start my journey of karmyoga

(If sometimes I feel lazy or not to do work in karmayog. Can I motivate myself by desires of moshka because karmayog is contary of desires?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked several questions.

**Questions**

**How to sacrifice all my karma to shri hari? Is it a mental state , if yes please describe?**

Gita has the answer to your question. There are basically 2 conditions. You should do your work not for your interest but for others and you should not hanker for the fruits of your work. An example would be to not go around and tell everyone that you have helped another person in order to get name and fame.

> O son of Kunti! In this world all actions, unless they are done as an
> offering to God (or as Yajna), become causes of bondage. Therefore,
> **work for the sake of God without personal attachment**.

**Gita 3.9**

> To work alone you have competence, and **not to claim their fruits**. Let
> not the longing for fruits be the motive force of your action. At the
> same time let not this attitude confirm you in indolent inaction.

**Gita 2.47**

**if problems arises I get a bit tense and anxious , so is being a little anxious and doubtful allowed in karma yoga?**

As a beginner it is natural to feel tense and anxious. However, with experience you will become calm naturally. Don't worry about it.

> Offering all actions to Me, your mind in unison with the spirit and
> free from desires and egotism, you fight without the slightest touch
> of hatred or **excitement**.

**Gita 3.30**

**Although, I can continue my work in doubt and anxiety is enjoying sensual pleasure allowed in karmyog (could arjun enjoy kingdom won after war being surrendered to shri hari/parmatma) In my case let's suppose I have completed my daily work can I go to restaurant/watch TV etc. Being surrendered to God I should completely renounce sensual pleasure and do my duties or is little pleasure allowed.If complete withdrawl of senses is required , what to do during free time(meditate on parmatma Or my free choice)**

The answer would depend on whether you are a householder or a monk. For monks Gita says the following:

> He who restrains the organs of action but continues to brood in his
> mind over the objects of sensual desire (enjoyed through them) – such
> a deluded person is called a hypocrite.

**Gita 3.6**

> But he who controlling all sense organs (by the power of his will) and
> becoming non-attached, lives a life of communion through dedicated
> action – such a person excels.

**Gita 3.7**

Complete abstinence from sexual desire is not required for householders.

**sometimes random lustful thoughts pop up in my mind and i immediately kill them. So is it possible to remain surrendered to God while being in lust for few span of time
Karmayog was told to surya dev also.If I want to read other texts regarding karma yoga (other than gita)Please give link or tell book and adhyay where it was told in detail**

Sudden stray sexual thoughts occur to most people. Don't dwell on them is Gita's advice.

**Now if I start karmyog I will fail initially due to( lack of self control+phone addiction +emotions and desires)
so please tell me something for self control which I should try for a week or two or month then I should start my journey of karmyoga**

Are you planning to become a monk or a householder? If you are a monk strict self-control is necessary. You will need to enforce self control through your will. Complete abstinence from desire is not required for householders.

**(If sometimes I feel lazy or not to do work in karmayog. Can I motivate myself by desires of moshka because karmayog is contary of desires?)**

This is a trivial issue. Karma Yoga is about servicing others and offering the fruits to God. It doesn't matter if you feel lazy occasionally.